# CSS: side navigation has no height

Tags: css

I've a side navigation on the left and on the right site I've some content displayed. The content has the full `width` of the site and my navigation none and I can't figure out why.

topbar / side navigation:

```
#topbar {
background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
width: 20%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
height:100%;
}
```

content styles:

```
.wrapper {
width:700px;
height:500px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#f7f7f7;
position:relative;
left:50%;
}
```

I used a wrapper for this content because I always want it to be next to the navigation

I appreciate every help and comment!

Comment: Can you provide some demo on fiddle?

Comment: never used it. I could try though

Comment: Don't use jSFiddle. Use the code snippet in the **edit question** section instead. We don't like code scattered over the internet, keep it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your two columns to control your all your pages and give each column a different background with a set minimum height:

```
.wrapper {
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  min-height: 600px;
}
#topnav {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}
#content .col-lg-9 {
  min-height: 610px;
  background: white;
}
#content .col-lg-3 {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}
```

the last piece of code covers your side nav and ensures that it's height is 100% at all times and same to that of you content/wrapper